# Profile matching query does not exist. DoesNotExist

Tags: matching

When I want to pass profile models data it says that Profile matching query does not exist.
I want to pass my profile model data to /settings page

Models.py
[enter image descr[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtG8P.png)]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/2[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6IVj.png)Epw7.png)iption here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2osri.png)

How can I solve this problem